# How to download MP3s from Amazon Cloud Player, Banshee and Raring Ringtail

Tags: firefox, banshee, music, amazon-mp3-downloader

There are a few questions relating to this, many of which have answers, but all are dated and not working for me.  I am trying to download my purchased music from Amazon, but am running into the classic "Linux can only download one file at a time" issue.  I tried the usual tricks of installing a User Agent plugin for Firefox, as well as trying to launch from Banshee, but it doesn't work.  At this point, I get to the "Download Cloud Player" link on Amazon, and when I click "Already Installed?  Launch Now" I get directed to the URL `amazoncloudplayer://launch` which Firefox says it has no registered applications for that protocol.  I wonder if this can be fixed by registering Banshee or something else with that protocol, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work. Any ideas?